# I print Picture X. I then try to print Picture Y but it prints Picture X again followed by Y. Please, how can I delete Picture X from a Python list?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, printers

This code is for printing badges for COVID-19 screening on a brother QL-800 printer.

I am using the amazing code someone created found here https://github.com/pklaus/brother_ql/tree/142cf744d89a912df729bbf15d35468d780559df/brother_ql

Apparently, each time I call the convert() or send() functions, the python code maintains the badge I am printing in a list.

So each time I try to print a new badge, it first prints all the old badges.

Can anyone see how to remove the badge image from the list after I do the convert() and send() commands to print?

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
import pygame
import time
from PIL import Image
from brother_ql.conversion import convert
from brother_ql.backends.helpers import send
from brother_ql.raster import BrotherQLRaster
from brother_ql.backends import backend_factory, guess_backend
#####################################################################################################
### Test QR-800 Printer
#####################################################################################################

# Here I just get two images each of size 1044x696
image1 = Image.open('RedBlack1_1044x696.png')
image2 = Image.open('RedBlack2_1044x696.png')

backend = 'linux_kernel'    # 'pyusb', 'linux_kernel', 'network'
model = 'QL-800' # your printer model.
printer = '/dev/usb/lp0'    
qlr = BrotherQLRaster(model)
qlr.exception_on_warning = True

badge = convert(
    qlr=qlr, 
    images=[image1],    #  Takes a list of file names or PIL objects.
    label='62red', 
    rotate='90',    # 'Auto', '0', '90', '270'
    threshold=70.0,    # Black and white threshold in percent.
    dither=False, 
    compress=False, 
    red=True,    # Only True if using Red/Black 62 mm label tape.
    dpi_600=False, 
    lq=False,    # True for low quality.
    no_cut=False
)
send(instructions=badge, printer_identifier=printer, backend_identifier=backend, blocking=True)
# THE ABOVE COMMAND PRINTS MY FIRST IMAGE (image1)

badge = convert(
    qlr=qlr, 
    images=[image2],    #  Takes a list of file names or PIL objects.
    label='62red', 
    rotate='90',    # 'Auto', '0', '90', '270'
    threshold=70.0,    # Black and white threshold in percent.
    dither=False, 
    compress=False, 
    red=True,    # Only True if using Red/Black 62 mm label tape.
    dpi_600=False, 
    lq=False,    # True for low quality.
    no_cut=False
)
send(instructions=badge, printer_identifier=printer, backend_identifier=backend, blocking=True)
# THE ABOVE COMMAND PRINTS BOTH IMAGES (image1 and image2).  Why is it printing image1 this time????

# QUESTION - HOW DO I PREVENT IT FROM PRINTING THE FIRST IMAGE TWICE?
```

Comment: Maybe try deleting `badge` after the first print and before converting the second to be sure it is starting afresh... just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation [here](http://brother-ql.net/readme.html) shows that convert adds a rasterised instruction for the current image to the data sent to the printer.  Likely, you need to reset the data to be sent before the second `send()`

One way would be to use `qlr = BrotherQLRaster(model)` before the second `convert()` but I can't test this to know for sure since I don't have a Brother printer.

Comment: Mike - THANK YOU!  You did it.  It is fixed!  God bless you and everyone at Stack Overflow!.

Comment: @BobGaines Glad to help.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please mark the answer as the accepted solution.